# Only layers of same output shape can be merged using sum mode. Layer shapes

Tags: python, keras

My model is U-Net implementation -

```
from keras.layers import Input, merge, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, 

UpSampling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model

def seg_score(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.0
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    true_sum = K.sum(y_true_f); pred_sum = K.sum(y_pred_f)
    if(true_sum > pred_sum):
        max_sum = true_sum
    else:
        max_sum = pred_sum
    return (intersection + smooth) / (max_sum + smooth)

def seg_score_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -seg_score(y_true, y_pred)

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)


def get_unet(num_color_component, dimension):

    img_rows = dimension; img_cols = dimension;
    inputs = Input((num_color_component, img_rows, img_cols))
    conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool3)
    conv4 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

    conv5 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool4)
    conv5 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv5)

    up6 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)

    conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv6)

    up7 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6), conv3], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv7 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv7)

    up8 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv8 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv8)

    up9 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8), conv1], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv9 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv9)

    conv10 = Convolution2D(1, 1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input=inputs, output=conv10)

    #model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), loss=seg_score_loss, metrics=[seg_score])
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])

    return model
```

I am getting error as follows-

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/zaverichintan/Chintan/PycharmProjects/CNN_wbc_identification/train.py", line 60, in 
>       model = mo.get_unet(num_color_component, filter_size);
>     File "/home/zaverichintan/Chintan/PycharmProjects/CNN_wbc_identification/models.py", line 63, in get_unet
>       up7 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6), conv3], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
>     File "/home/zaverichintan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 456, in merge
>       name=name)
>     File "/home/zaverichintan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 107, in **init**
>       node_indices, tensor_indices)
>     File "/home/zaverichintan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 187, in _arguments_validation
>       'Layer shapes: %s' % (input_shapes))
>   ValueError: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, 0, 16, 256), (None, 0, 16, 128)]

Changed Concat axis to 3 then I am getting this -

> File "/home/zaverichintan/Chintan/PycharmProjects/CNN_wbc_identification/train.py", line 60, in 
>       model = mo.get_unet(num_color_component, filter_size);
>     File "/home/zaverichintan/Chintan/PycharmProjects/CNN_wbc_identification/models.py", line 71, in get_unet
>       up8 = keras.layers.merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
>     File "/home/zaverichintan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 456, in merge
>       name=name)
>     File "/home/zaverichintan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 107, in **init**
>       node_indices, tensor_indices)
>     File "/home/zaverichintan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py", line 187, in _arguments_validation
>       'Layer shapes: %s' % (input_shapes))
>   ValueError: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, 0, 32, 128), (None, 1, 32, 64)]

Comment: You either need to change your `conat_axis` to the axis which have differing dimensions, or alter your differing axis dimensions to be equal.

Comment: conat_axis will be ?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, `concat_axis`.

Comment: Okay!, So what should be its value set to ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I assume the value should be set based on the structure of Convolutional NNs, or it is problem specific. Maybe someone with more knowledge can tell right off the bat what the issue is based on how ConvNNs are structured, but as far as being problem specific, I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: Doing a quick google search finds something that might be of use ( https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2626 ), have you tried looking for any supporting documents?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward :

> ValueError: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, 0, 16, 256), (None, 0, 16, 128)]

you have :

```
up6 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
```

they explicitely say that the shapes should be the same ***except for the concat axis***

the dimension where the shape is different is the 3rd dimension (one is 256, the other is 128). So you should set the concat axis to 3 not 1. As in :

```
up6 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=3)
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `image_data_format": "channels_first"` as described here https://keras.io/backend/ or change the input to

```
 inputs = Input((img_rows, img_cols, num_color_component))
```

Then the `concat_axis` has to correspond with data format.

Here is an example of how to implement a U-net in Keras: https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/blob/master/train.py#L34